# how to update SSRS execution account automatically through powershell?

Tags: sql-server, powershell, ssrs-2016

I need to update the password for the SSRS Execution account for every 15 days. How can I automate this process using powershell or some other scripting?

Comment: This might help. https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2010/11/03/use-powershell-to-change-sql-server-service-accounts/

Answer (score 0):

**Changing the passwords:**

If you are using a Active Directory account you can use the ActiveDirectory PowerShell module.

```
Set-ADAccountPassword -Identity elisada -OldPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText "p@ssw0rd" -Force) -NewPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText "qwert@12345" -Force)
```

If you are using a Sql Server user than it would be using T-SQL

```
ALTER LOGIN UserName WITH PASSWORD = 'P@ssw0rd';  
    GO
```

**Updating the Service:**

```
$service = gwmi win32_service -computer [computername] -filter "name='ReportServer'"
$service.change($null,$null,$null,$null,$null,$null,$null,"P@ssw0rd")
```